# SQL Server Inquiry - Trying to pull order line items that include at least one specific part

Tags: sql-server, orders

I'm trying to run a query in which if an order includes like '%abc%', it shows me those POs with its respective line items. I don't only want the query to just show those '%abc%' line items. I want to be able to also see other line items included in those POs that include '%abc%'.

Comment: would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please try tu help us with little bit better question. To start with please add some example data and add the code you have tried and then add the result set you want to get from the data you provided...

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.